# rails 4 belongs_to and has_many to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to

I have an Opportunity model that belongs_to Section model.
Section has_many opportunities.

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :section
```

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :opportunities
```

Opportunity model has to have section_id but i would like to be able to also have many sections as involved sections in some cases.

how would it be possible to create?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a many-to-many association between, `Opportunity` and `Section`, for that you need to create a connecting table between the two, create a migration

```
create_table :opportunities_sections, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :opportunity
  t.belongs_to :section
end
```

Then in `Opportunity` model, add this line

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :sections
```

In `Section` model, add this line

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :opportunities
```

Finally, remove `section_id` column from `opportunities` table.

More info on `has_and_belongs_to_many` association here

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

You can also achieve `many-to-many` association via `has_many through` association, the basic difference between `has_and_belongs_to_many` and `has_many through` is you can create a model class for the connecting table, that way you get more flexibility in terms of saving any additional data with the connection. More info here

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

What to choose?

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Rails guides got all the answers!

Comment: Perhaps also add the `has_many :through` option and explain the differences...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.